# Applying case_when across two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(0,0,3), C = c(3,2,1)) 
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(0, 2, 4), B = c(1,0,3), C = c(0,1,4))
```

I would like to generate a third dataframe by applying some conditional logic across `df1` and `df2`, by comparing the entries between equivalently named columns. So the logic would be:

```
df1$A == 0 and df2$A>0         ~ df3$A = "colonised"
df1$A < df2$A and df1$A != 0   ~ df3$A = "increased"
df1$A == df2$A and df1$A >0    ~ df3$A = "stable"
df1$A > df2$A  and df2$A != 0  ~ df3$A = "decreased"
df1$A>0 and df2$A == 0         ~ df3$A = "extinct"
```

These rules would be applied for each respective column, so df1$B v df2$B and df1$C v df2$C. The example above would give the result for `df3` as:

```
  A         B         C
1 extinct   colonised extinct
2 stable    stable    decreased
3 increased stable    increased
```

Comment: Your last logic isn't going to fire, since if `A1 > 0 && A2 == 0`, then it is certainly true that `A1 > A2`, your fourth criterion. The order matters, the first that matches is used.

Comment: ok. thanks for that. Will update above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option utilizing `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
map2_dfr(.x = df1,
         .y = df2,
         ~ case_when(.x == 0 & .y > 0 ~ "colonised",
                     .x > 0 & .y == 0 ~ "extinct",
                     .x < .y ~ "increased",
                     .x == .y ~ "stable",
                     .x > .y ~ "decreased"))

  A         B         C        
  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 extinct   colonised extinct  
2 stable    stable    decreased
3 increased stable    increased
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` alone:

```r
Map(function(x1, x2) 
  case_when(
    x1 == 0 & x2 > 0 ~ "colonised",
    x1 < x2          ~ "increased",
    x1 == x2         ~ "stable",
    x1 > x2          ~ "decreased",
    x1 > 0 & x2 == 0 ~ "extinct"),
  df1, df2) %>%
  as_tibble()
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   A         B         C        
#   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 decreased colonised decreased
# 2 stable    stable    decreased
# 3 increased stable    increased
```

`dplyr` and `purrr`

```r
purrr::pmap_dfr(list(df1, df2), 
                ~ case_when(
                  ..1 == 0 & ..2 > 0 ~ "colonised",
                  ..1 < ..2          ~ "increased",
                  ..1 == ..2         ~ "stable",
                  ..1 > ..2          ~ "decreased",
                  ..1 > 0 & ..2 == 0 ~ "extinct"))
```

As @tmfmnk shows, you can also use the `purrr::map2*` variants. Same effect.

Comment: Very clever. I didn't realise `purrr::map` could work like that.

Comment: (Anthony, I mistakenly had `&&` in the last case, fixed. If you're testing it, please update.)

Comment: ... though it is still the case that your last case will never be used.